# How would one generate a set of $x$ random values conforming to a certain criteria?

Tags: statistics, random

I basically want to generate a set of $x$ numbers given $x$, a minimum, maximum and average. The set of numbers must conform, yielding the given average, with the smallest number being the given minimum, and the largest being the given maximum.

Also, a second set, but different from the first would conform to all requirements of the first, except the minimum could be equal to or greater than the given minimum, and the maximum could be equal to or less than the given maximum.

I would prefer to use some freely, easy, available tool or formula to generate these rather than write a complicated program, if possible.

Comment: You need more information than max, min and average. In fact, there are infinite distributions which would fit into that category. More information is needed about the distribution you want to use. In general, the methodolgy around generated random samples is to create a CDF, invert it, and use uniform random variables (standard in most prob. packages) to get the desired distribution

Comment: @jameselmore, yes there may be an infinite number of these, but I need just 1 that conforms to the criteria. What other information would be required?